# Precedence for Basic Auth & IP white list

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, basic-authentication

I am setting up Basic authentication for few internal endpoints in a spring boot application. I have a use case to do the IP white list validation before doing the Basic Auth check. Using the WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter configure method I am able to achieve this but the order is reversed where basic authentication is being done before ip white list authorization.

Is there a way to have the IP white list take precedence before basic auth?

Using the below code for web security

```
return new WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter() {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .csrf()
                .disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest()
            .access("(hasIpAddress('xx.xx.xx.xx') and isAuthenticated()")
            .and()
            .httpBasic();
    }
}
```

Comment: There isn't a built-in way. However, the easiest way is to implement your own custom filter. Just implement `javax.servlet.Filter`. You could add the filter in your Spring configuration with `addFilterBefore`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare in the order you want in the configuration.

```
@Component
public class IPWhiteLister implements AuthenticationProvider {
     
   Set<String> whitelist = new HashSet<String>();
 
    public CustomIpAuthenticationProvider() {
        whitelist.add("10.1.1.1");
        whitelist.add("172.1.1.1");
    }
 
    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication auth) throws AuthenticationException {
        WebAuthenticationDetails details = (WebAuthenticationDetails) auth.getDetails();
        String userIp = details.getRemoteAddress();
        if(! whitelist.contains(userIp)){
            throw new BadCredentialsException("Invalid IP Address");
        }
        return auth;
}
```

and follow steps from https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-multiple-auth-providers to use multiple authentication providers. You have to also override another configure method for building AuthenticationManagerBuilder. 
You can add multiple Authentication Providers by method authenticationProvider. It's little deceptive as signature doesn't say it will allow you to add more than one authentication providers.

```
    public class ApplicationSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
    {

      Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ApplicationSecurity.class);

      @Autowired
      private IPWhiteListFilter ipWhiteListFilter;
      @Override
      protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth){
        auth.authenticationProvider(ipWhiteListFilter);
        // FOLLOWING is just an example
        auth.authenticationProvider(userNamePasswordAuthenticator)
      }
   ...
```

Instead of the following the line in your code

```
.access("(hasIpAddress('xx.xx.xx.xx') and isAuthenticated()")
```

Just use

```
.authenticated()
```

Comment: Can you be more specific. I have added my code snippet in the question